# Lost transparency in SDL surfaces drawn manually

Tags: rendering, sdl, image, transparency

I want to create `SDL_Surface` objects for each layer of my 2d tile-based map so that I have to render only one surface per layer rather than too many tiles. With normal tiles which do not have transparent areas this works well, however I am not able to create a `SDL_Surface` with transparent pixels everywhere to be able to draw some tiles on specific parts which should be visible (I do **NOT** want the whole surface to appear with a specific opacity - I want to create overlaying tiles where one can look through).

Currently I am creating my layers like this to draw with `SDL_BlitSurface` on them:

```
SDL_Surface* layer =
    SDL_CreateRGBSurface(
        SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_SRCALPHA,
        layerWidth, layerHeight, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

If you have a look at this screenshot I have provided here

[image: Transparency Fail]

you can see that the bottom layer with no transparent parts gets rendered correctly. However the overlay with the tree tile (which is transparent in the top left corner) is drawn own its own surface which is black and not transparent as expected. The expected result (concerning the transparency) can be seen here

[image: Expected transparency]

**Can anyone explain me how to handle surfaces which are actually transparent rather than drawing all my overlay tiles separately?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying a few things in desperation I was able to fix this issue! First of all I have filled the `SDL_Surface` objects with magenta

```
SDL_FillRect(layer, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(layer->format, 255, 0, 255));
```

then I noticed I have tried to handle alpha while drawing to the layer but I forgot to think about the `SDL_BlitSurface` call to the screen! Just one line above this call I had to add

```
SDL_SetColorKey(layer, SDL_SRCCOLORKEY, SDL_MapRGB(layer->format, 255, 0, 255));
```

and that did it!